# How do you permutate through a list of lists (of strings)? Can you do it with a set?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I would like an output of

`nums = (("2q","3q","4q","3q"),("1q"), ("1q","2q"))`

to result in:

`pairs = (("2q", "3q"), ("2q", "1q"),("1q","2q")).......`

Is that possible?

Would it work better if I have a set more like:

`nums = (("2q,3q,4q,3q"),("1q"), ("1q,2q"))`

and use a split?

Comment: Your result is quite confusing, can you describe it more? Do u want to iterate through every elements in the list?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal....

Comment: is it even possible?  I just want to know what I can do with permutations.

Comment: see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-permutation-given-string-using-inbuilt-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had a typo in your `nums`... if you intended them all to be tuples, the `("1q")` has to have a comma, like `("1q",)`:

```
nums = (("2q","3q","4q","3q"),("1q",), ("1q","2q"))
```

If the input is a tuple of tuples (or list of lists, etc), the following gives you all the pairs assuming it's ok to pick a value twice:

```
import itertools
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

out = list(distinct_permutations(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nums), r=2))

print(out)
[('1q', '1q'), ('1q', '2q'), ('1q', '3q'), ('1q', '4q'), ('2q', '1q'), ('2q', '2q'), ('2q', '3q'), ('2q', '4q'), ('3q', '1q'), ('3q', '2q'), ('3q', '3q'), ('3q', '4q'), ('4q', '1q'), ('4q', '2q'), ('4q', '3q')]
```

If you don't want duplicates in the pairs, you can use `set` to eliminate them before running it:

```
out_no_duplicates = list(distinct_permutations(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nums)), r=2))

print(out_no_duplicates)
[('1q', '2q'), ('1q', '3q'), ('1q', '4q'), ('2q', '1q'), ('2q', '3q'), ('2q', '4q'), ('3q', '1q'), ('3q', '2q'), ('3q', '4q'), ('4q', '1q'), ('4q', '2q'), ('4q', '3q')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for literal permutations, Check out itertools.permutations https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Example from:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-permutations/

```
from itertools import permutations  

a = 'string value here.' # list or string value.
a = ['2q', '3q', '4q'] #... Add other items here.
p = permutations(a,2)   #for pairs of len 2

# Print the obtained permutations  
for j in list(p):  
    print(j)  

#For multiple length clusters..
for c in range(min_cluster_len, max_cluster_len): 
    for j in list(permutations(a, c)):
        print(j)

#Output: 
('2q', '3q')
('2q', '4q')
('2q', '5q')
('3q', '2q')
('3q', '4q')
('3q', '5q')
('4q', '2q')
('4q', '3q')
('4q', '5q')
('5q', '2q')
('5q', '3q')
('5q', '4q')
('2q', '3q', '4q')
('2q', '3q', '5q')
('2q', '4q', '3q')
...
```

If order doesn't matter, i.e. (2q, 3q) == (3q, 2q), use itertools.combinations instead.

For your actual questions data, looks like you need to split by comma if anything has a length > x, and I'm not sure how you're grouping these so not entirely sure.  Could also use regex, but not ideal.

Comment: what was your input string that generated the output?

Comment: It's all in post.. the list of values:  a = ['2q', '3q', '4q'] #... Add other items here.
So... make a list of all possible values... all_vals = ['1q', '2q' ... 'Nq']

Comment: I see you showed two use cases of permutations in your output

Comment: No, I nested the same use case -- for varying length.